# How to improve MySQL performance Insert / update on duplicate for below Table ,Statement and JDBC code

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is my Table creation text:

```
CREATE TABLE `DailyReporting` (
    `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `QT_ST_CD` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `CNSM_MT_CD` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `CHANNEL` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `ORGN_QT_DT_ET` date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PRTNR_CD` BIGINT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    `SALE_DT` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `QT_START` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    `NP6` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    `APPS` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    `CreatedDate` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `LastUpdatedDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE KEY `uk_dailyReporting` (`ORGN_QT_DT_ET`,`PRTNR_CD`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23203 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

My Insert / update statment is like as follows:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO "+tableName+
                    " (QT_ST_CD, CNSM_MT_CD,CHANNEL,ORGN_QT_DT_ET,PRTNR_CD,SALE_DT,QT_START,NP6,APPS) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"+
                    " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE QT_ST_CD=VALUES(QT_ST_CD),CNSM_MT_CD=VALUES(CNSM_MT_CD),CHANNEL=VALUES(CHANNEL),SALE_DT=VALUES(SALE_DT),QT_START=VALUES(QT_START),NP6=VALUES(NP6),APPS=VALUES(APPS)";
            preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            for (int i = 0; i < dailyReports.size(); i++) {
                DailyReportVO dailRprt = dailyReports.get(i);
//              if (counter < batchSize) {
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, dailRprt.getQT_ST_CD());
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, dailRprt.getCNSM_MT_CD());
                    preparedStatement.setString(3, dailRprt.getCHANNEL());
                    java.util.Date utilDate = dailRprt.getORGN_QT_DT_ET();
                    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
                    preparedStatement.setDate(4, sqlDate);
                    preparedStatement.setLong(5, dailRprt.getPRTNR_CD());
                    java.util.Date utilDate2 = dailRprt.getSALE_DT();
                    if (utilDate2 != null) {
                        java.sql.Date sqlDate2 = new java.sql.Date(utilDate2.getTime());
                        preparedStatement.setDate(6, (Date) sqlDate2);
                    } else {
                        preparedStatement.setDate(6, null);
                    }
                    preparedStatement.setInt(7, dailRprt.getQT_START());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(8, dailRprt.getNP6());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(9, dailRprt.getAPPS());
//                  preparedStatement.addBatch();
                    boolean result=preparedStatement.execute();
                    counter++;
                    totalcount++;

            }
```

With current MySQL insert/update performance it is taking 20 mins for 6000 records. Where as I need to import more than 150k records per day.

Please share your opinion on my existing code or on statments.

Comment: re-use your prepared statement, also use transactions and commit every 100 or so rows

Comment: Did you check the performance on the MySQL server side? Seems more like a server optimization issue. What is the performance difference if the insert operation is used compared to the list of updates.

Comment: While you can certainly optimize your method, inserting row by row into a table with 20k rows should typically give you a throughput in the range of some hundred inserts per second, not 5 inserts/s. This indicates that there might be an underlying problem here (outside of the code, although I would try wombats suggestion). You need to identify the bootleneck. I'd try to time everything, e.g. check what `dailyReports.get(i);` does and how long it takes. You may have triggers on your table that do some complicated stuff, or a slow connection; maybe other transactions are blocking?

Comment: Have you tried using `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` in your connection string along with using `addBatch` and `executeBatch` in your Java code?